# How to rename a C function name in its definition at runtime

Tags: c

Can anyone please solve the following problem for me:

Problem: Let say there are two functions `foo()` and `bar()` defined as

```
void bar()
{
    printf("bar\n");
}

void foo()
{
    printf("foo\n");
    bar();
}
```

So, here I want to change the function name bar to bar_test in its definition but not in calling. This should be runtime and the source code should not be modified.

The expected output is as below:

```
void bar_test()
{
    printf("bar\n");
}

void foo()
{
    printf("foo\n");
    bar();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this? C has no concept of the runtime name of a function (other than as debugging symbols).

Comment: You can't rename functions,variables, classes,..... in any programming language. In c, a name presents a pointers to location in the memory and that is static.In addition, even if you was able to change it's name, you will have then to change it's calling in the source code.

Comment: The program doesn't output itself, so your "the expected output is as follows" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I believe during compile-time those function names are erased anyway

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Answer (score 5):

One way would be to have a macro like

```
#define bar() bar_test()
```

Now calling `bar()` by the macro calls `bar_test()`

The function which is defined should be called as per the standard.
There is no option to change the function name during runtime and it doesn't make sense also.

Comment: Actually, I've a problem in c unit test framework(mock functions). 
If there are two functions defined in same file then assembler resolve the function call before linker has a chance to wrap it.
By doing above thing I want to make function bar() undefined so that linker can wrap it to the __wrap_bar() function.

Comment: Thanks Gopi... but in this way the function name bar() during calling of it will also be changed which is not desired. That is inside definition of foo(), bar should remain as it is.

Comment: This problem comes as a solution of another problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29212963/how-to-overcome-from-the-limitation-of-mock-functions